# I can't retrieve data from a document in Firestore, but I am not getting any errors

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I am confused.
I have no problems sending data to Firestore, but for some reason I cannot view it.
I am just getting a blank page with nothing on it, and I am not getting any errors.

**This is the Vue component I use to get data from a specific document based on it's ID**

```
<template>
    <div v-if="content">{{ content.text }}</div>
</template>

<script>
import db from '@/firebase/config'
export default {
    name: 'FormTest',
    data() {
        return {
            content: null
            
        }
    },
    created() {
        let ref = db.collection('test').where('id', '==', this.$route.params.id)
        ref.get().then(snapshot => {
            snapshot.forEach(doc => {
                this.content = doc.data()
                this.content.id = doc.id
            })
        })
    }
    
}
</script>
```

**This is the route that I use for the component, where I access the individual document based on it's ID**

```
  {
    path: '/form-test/:id',
    name: 'FormTest',
    component: FormTest,
  }
```

**This is my Firebase config file** (I removed the id's and key for this post)

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/firestore'
import 'firebase/auth'
import 'firebase/storage'

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    databaseURL: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "",
    appId: "",
    measurementId: ""
  };

  // init firebase
  const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
  firebaseApp.firestore().settings({ timestampsInSnapshot: true })

  // init services

  const projectFirestore = firebase.firestore()
  const projectAuth = firebase.auth()
  const projectStorage = firebase.storage()

  // timestamp

  const timestamp = firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp

  export {projectFirestore, projectAuth, projectStorage, timestamp}
  export default firebaseApp.firestore()
```

**And these are the rules**

```
match /test/{docId} {
  allow write, delete: if request.auth != null;
  allow read: if request.time < timestamp.date(2021, 12, 26);
}
```

Comment: If you change `content: null` to `content: { text: null }`, does that help? As the `content.text` property doesn't exist at the point the component is created, it would be unreactive.

Comment: Sadly no. I am still getting a blank screen, and no errors in the console.

Comment: For future reference, if this happens to anyone in the future, I would make sure about a couple of things:
   - Is Firestore returning the data? (do a console.log)
   - Is the id passed to the where filter the correct one?